# How to create a text background - two giant numbers (score counter)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a rock paper scissors game as part of the TOP curriculum.

I want to display the human score and computer score as two GIANT digits shown behind all other elements. Preferably the digits take up 50% of the screen's width each.

For the life of me, I can't get this to work. So far, my code looks like this:

https://codepen.io/givemeskills/pen/GRjMYPN

```css
#testContainer {
  max-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
}

#test {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: x;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="testContainer">
  <div id="test">
    <p id="humanScoreDispTest">3</p>
    <p id="compScoreDispTest">3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added borders in a vain attempt to understand what I'm doing. Ideally I'd like the font size to be as big as possible, but it just seems to affect the size of the page itself.

I apologize if this question isn't very well put. I'm very new to all this.

Comment: You can adjust their size via css `#humanScoreDispTest, #compScoreDispTest {
  font-size: 5em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the font-size property. You wrote just an x, which is not a valid value (also checked it back to the CSS validator). You have to write something like 4rem or in another unit like 400%.

If you want to adjust the font height (=font-size) so that the font takes up 50% of the width, it's not so easy. Different fonts have a different width / height proportion, also depending on the letter. For this you would need JavaScript, pure CSS isn't enough. But I think, that cannot be your goal, here is an example to show why: If the computer have the result 100 and the human the result 5, the 5 would be a lot bigger than the 100.

Comment: I understand I can change font size, the CSS is just blank for that.  if I change font size to say 400px it just causes the page height to increase along with the font. I need the each number to take up 100% height of page and 50% of the width so it fits perfectly. the score maxes out at 5 so your second point isn't an issue. any ideas?

Comment: @giveMeSkills you can set the height using the `vh`(view height) unit instead of pixels. So, try a number like 90vh to make their size close to view height of the browser.